# Spherical magnetic bearing from electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism

Would it be possible to build a magnetic bearing with this design:

A hollow metal sphere with an electric coil solenoid in the center. The electromagnetic field from the coil is transfered to the metal sphere by electromagnetic induction. The induced EM field in the metal sphere has the same polarity as the EM field of the coil, causing the coil and the metal sphere to repel one another.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would make a spherical magnetic bearing from an electromagnet.
There are six windings. Direction of current in each of the six windings controls the direction the that the inner sphere (the armature) moves.

[image: Spherical Electromagnet]

[image: Paper model showing magnetic fields based on current]

[image: Same as above but from different angle]

The device is free and open source.
[You can read more about it here if you want.](http://www.justodians.org/SphericalMagnet/PatentApp.htm)
:)